# Getting Value from Radio with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I'm looking for a way to get my value from a radio button.  I have the html right here.

```
<div id="main_">
    <div class="facts_div">
        <span class="question"></span>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div id = "next_button">
    <form>
        <input id="x" type="button" class="myBtn" value="Press Me">
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery code.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
```

//

```
var answers = 
[["Fee","Fi","Fo"], 
["La","Dee","Da"]],
questions = 
["Fee-ing?",
"La-ing?"],
corAns = ["Fee", "La"];

var counter = 0;
var correctAnswers = 0;

var $facts = $('#main_ .facts_div'),
$question = $facts.find('.question'),
$ul = $facts.find('ul'),
$btn = $('.myBtn');


$btn.on('click', function() {
    if (counter < questions.length) {
        $question.text(questions[counter]);

        var ansstring = $.map(answers[counter], function(value) {
            return '<li><input type="radio" name="ans" value="0"/>'
            + value + '</li>'}).join('');
        $ul.html(ansstring);
        alert($('input[name="ans"]:checked').val())
        //if ($('input[name=ans]:checked').val() == corAns[counter]) {
            //correctAnswers++;
        //}
    }
    else {
        $facts.text('You are done with the quiz ' + correctAnswers);
        $(this).hide()
    }
    counter++;
});



//    
});
```

As you can tell, it keeps returning undefined, and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Incidentally, the value is to measure whether this is a correct or incorrect answer in a quiz I am making.  So, eventually I will need to use `array[counter]` in an if statement.  But, I broke this apart to test and tweak and figure out how to get the value.

Comment: Is anything checked on page load?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, so no.

Comment: So, in your code, your alerting the checked radio buttons value on page-load, but since nothing is checked on page load, you're receiving undefined

Comment: So, should I nest another onclick that deals with the radio button and then add the value to `correctAnswers` that way?

Comment: Ok, I don't know if I'm being unclear here or not, but maybe I should just post the entire quiz, rather than this snippet.  I want to cycle through questions dynamically, and then when a radio button choice is selected, return the value to test.  If it is in fact the correct answer I would like it to be added to correctAnswers.

Comment: best suggestion is create a live demo with some sample data in jsfiddle. That demo can then be modified by others to help you along

Comment: I feel as if you're making this extremely complicated when it doesn't have to be, I'm going to post a quick solution that seems to be of significantly less code.

Comment: This wasn't the code when I answered the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're making this much more complicated than needed. You simply need an array of correct answers, and then on button click just loop and check the answers (you'll see the play by play in the comments):

```
$btn.on('click', function() {
    //Your answers array should never be longer than your questions length, so that check is a bit useless, scrap it
    //Lets first gather all your answers into an array, the .map function is built for this:

    var currentAnswers = $('input[name="ans"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    //Now that we have all the checked radio buttons from the quiz, loop and compare to your answers array, if they match, do something
    //You have a 2D array of answers, then one of correct answers, you only need 1 array, and that should contain the correct responses, so eliminate the 2D array
    //Your correct answers should be: corAns = ["Fee", "La"];

    var correct = 0; //current number of correct answers
    for (var i = 0; i < currentAnswers.length; i++) {
        if (currentAnswers[i] == corAns[i]) {
            correct++; //Increment correct variable
        }
    }
});
```

Of course you may want a check to make sure the user has answered everything or else in the end an array could end up out of bounds and cause an error.

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch.  I'm sorry if I sounded snarky in any of my comments, that was not my intention.  I haven't been doing this very long at all.  Sometimes, it gets a little frustrating (in a good way though).  This way is a lot more elegant.

Comment: Developing gets that way, there are plenty of different ways to do things. Keep at it, keep asking questions! Happy to help! -@JerryWalker

Comment: I have one more question... If there is only one array for the entire quiz, then how will I dynamically add all the answers?  The only answers shown will, in fact, be the right answers.